# iPod Library access in iPhone OS 3.0

Tags: iphone

One of the new developer features in version 3.0 of the iPhone OS allows users to select music from their own library to listen to within applications via the MPMediaPickerController class.

Is there a way to make the media picker appear in landscape mode for applications that support this device orientation?

Answer (score 3):

It won't rotate correctly, even if you set shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation. Confirmation of this comes from a blog:

"I'll make a really long story really short by noting that this little bastard is hardwired for portrait use. I could get it into various stages of landscape, but when the orientation was rotated correctly, the touch inputs and drags weren't. If I could get the sizing right, then the orientation was wrong. And so on. I even cashed in one of my Apple developer tech support incidents looking for a solution (they confirmed my conclusion about the portrait limitation)."

http://hunter.pairsite.com/blogs/20090628/

Answer (score 1):

The MPMediaPickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class does support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private; do not modify the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but one working solution I just found is putting the MPMediaPickerController inside UIPopOverController.